# sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts

Tags: sudo

Can anyone suggest how I can avoid this situation? It never asks for password but still complains the password is wrong.

```
sudo su -
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

sudoers file entry :

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%domain\\my_engineering ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Thank you.

Comment: we added the eng group to the domain and users are able to login to the VM but failing to get sudo access. Yes both are tried but same issue.

Comment: `sudo su` switches to the user `root` which is not enabled by default, no password is set for the user `root`...

Comment: @mook765 With `sudo`, you don't need a password for `su`. `sudo su -` works just fine to give a root shell without the `root` account being enabled.

Comment: %domain\\my_engineering ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL also tried but no luck.  i am new to ubuntu. where as in redhat i went well but in ubuntu somewhere i  should look into but not getting some one who solved this please suggest me. Thank you :)\

Comment: Perhaps you will find something helpful here: [Allow AD Groups to SUDO](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150476/allow-ad-groups-to-sudo)

Comment: %domain\\my_engineering ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL  also tried but no luck , if anyone worked on this kind of issues. Please update here thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to have sudo not asking a password you'd use `ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` attached to the user or to the group of your choice in the configuration file.

I'd suggest you to see `man sudoers` or a tutorial like [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/sudo-beginners-guide/).

I prefer the man page first, though.

By the way, in order to get a `root` shell you can also run `sudo -s -H`. Again, the man page can be of help.

Comment: Hi Uqbar, tried already which you suggested commands but here domain users able to login and sudo access cant.   %domain\\my_engineering ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL   also tried but no luck. Please suggest me

Comment: I see now that you are trying to use Windows authentication services. Can those users log in?What does your Linux system says when they run the "id" command? Do you want them to be asked for the password or not?